# CSS box-shadow to one direction

Tags: shadow, css

I am requested to make the following design:

[image]

Here's how I'm trying to achieve the cascaded shadow:

```
box-shadow: -6px 0px 10px #514E49
```

But it results in the shadow being displayed in the opposite direction:

[image]

I tried changing the `h-shadow` parameter to `6px`, but then the shadow is only visible in the rightmost edge.

I tried using `inset` as [Emil suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14425575/75500), but it causes the `v-shadow` to display inset as well and becomes visible inside the box, which should be avoided, here is what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to avoid `float:right` and reversing the menu is by using a negative spread and increased h-shadow like this:

```
.box {
    background: #817E77;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    box-shadow: inset 10px 0px 10px -4px #514E49;
    float:left;
}
```

[jsFiddle result](http://jsfiddle.net/shimmy/6V7Et/7/)

Comment: Just like using negative h-shadow moved the shadow along its x-axis negatively (and appeared on the left), moving it forward while expanding the spread upwards out of view would create the look you're aiming for with pure CSS rather than messing with the HTML.

Comment: Love this solution! But why `-webkit-box-shadow`? The prefix isn't needed for anything anymore except Blackberry...

Answer (score 4):

try this:

`box-shadow:inset 6px 0px 10px #514E49;`

edit:

```
box-shadow: 6px 0px 10px #514E49;
float:right;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6V7Et/4/

you have to reverse the order of the menu

Comment: I tried that but it's causing the `v-shadow` to be inset as well, and then displays inside the box, which I don't want, I'll update my question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will best be tackled with z-index since your problem is the other divs are hiding the previously rendered ones.

so:

```
.box {
    ....your stuff here....
    float:right
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XKNn4/

Comment: The menu is generated dynamically. I prefer not to pollute the CSS or mess with the `z-index` if there are alternative ways.

Comment: As Emil said, your idea to set `float: right` was the answer, however the `z-index` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, one that doesn't involve reversing the order of the menu or using `z-index` would be to put the `box-shadow` on a pseudo-element.

## [***demo***](http://dabblet.com/gist/4579430)

Relevant **CSS**:

```
li {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 6px 0px 10px #514E49;
    /* the other styles */
}
li:not(:first-child):after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 100%; width: 100%; height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 6px 0px 10px #514E49;
    content: '';
}
```